# How to populate various aspects in help()

Tags: python, documentation, pydoc

In looking at `help()` on a few different modules, it often lists the following items:

Module Docs:

```
MODULE DOCS
    http://docs.python.org/library/os
```

Classes:

```
CLASSES
    __builtin__.object
        posix.stat_result
```

Data:

```
DATA
    EX_CANTCREAT = 73
```

Version:

```
VERSION
    (7, 0, 2)
```

How are these four items created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help texts are extracted from the python files's doctrings by the [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc) module.
You can read more about pydoc on [the Python Devguide](https://devguide.python.org/documenting/). 
Pydoc extracts information about the module, for example which classes and functions are defined, what data, et cetera.

Try running for example `pydoc os` (or `help(os)`) and compare it to the module source code: `/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py`